# pg_hba.conf split file for easier deployment

Tags: postgresql, deployment

The pg_hba.conf file of postgres contains some lines for every application which runs on our server.

Is there a way to split the config file into several parts?

Maybe like this:

```
pg_hba.conf.d/
 foo.conf
 bar.conf
 ...
```

Background: Deployment is much easier if you can work with files, and not patch a file.

Comment: FWIW, I've never come across a way to do it, nor do the docs indicate that it is possible.

Comment: You can emulate this with a script file, that will create config file from config parts before starting / restarting the server.

Comment: Some want to close this question, since it is not about programming. I think pg_hba.conf is never about programming. That's why I searched for "pg_hba.conf" on stackexchange.org first. This showed that almost all question about this file where asked on stackoverflow. That's why I posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this at the time of writing (Pg 9.3 and older), nor is there any sign it's planned for 9.4.

In 9.3 you can use `include_dir` to load `postgresql.conf` snippets, but there's no plan to integrate `pg_hba.conf` into `postgresql.conf` in a way that'd let you use this mechanism.

You'll need to do it with an external tool as part of your configuration management.